# How to manually trigger right click/context menu in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, right-click

I am trying to add a button and when we click the button it will trigger the right click. I know how to do it in jQuery, but how we do it in react?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UI library such as Material UI, you can take a look at the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#context-menu)

If you want to do it without any dependency, I invite you to watch this [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-create-a-right-click-menu-using-react)

Comment: I am not talking about how we create a right-click menu.
In my case, I am using the library [react-contextmenu](https://github.com/vkbansal/react-contextmenu) so I have the right-click menu already, but I want to add a button as well so that the user has a choice to right-click or click the button to open the same menu.